# Central Limit Theorem - Different Forms

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, summation, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

Given the following function:

$W_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\Pi_{k=1}^{\infty}\log(U_k)$ where $U_k$ is uniformly distributed from $1$ to $e$.

Does $\{W_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ converge in distribution?

I found that: $\log(\Pi_{k=1}^{\infty}U_k)$ is equivalent to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \log(U_k)$ which can be called $S_n$.

$W_n$ can then be written as  $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$. The answers says that this function has the distribution $\mathcal{N}(\sqrt{n}E[\log(U_k)],V[\log(U_k])$ where $V$ is variance. The final result is that it does not converge because its mean is dependent on $n$.

I am having trouble understanding where the multiplication by $\sqrt{n}$ comes from.

I know that $\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sqrt{n\sigma^2}}$ has the distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ by the central limit theorem. I also saw in my book that $\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sqrt{n}}$ has the distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$.

I am just having trouble understanding how modifying that equation has the corresponding effect on the distribution.

Comment: Just checking, the product in outside of logarithm?

Comment: No sorry, Ill edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe by $S_n$, you intend to mean $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \log(U_k).$

\begin{align}
E\left[ \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right] &= \frac1{\sqrt{n}}E\left[\sum_{k=1}^n \log(U_k) \right] \\
&= \frac1{\sqrt{n}}\left(n E(\log(U_1 \right)))\\
&= \sqrt{n} E(\log(U_1))
\end{align}

\begin{align}
V\left[ \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right] &= \frac1{n}V\left[\sum_{k=1}^n \log(U_k) \right] \\
&= \frac1{n}\left(n V(\log(U_1 \right)))\\
&= V(\log(U_1))
\end{align}

Comment: Ok I see it now. It was really very simple, thank you Siong